# How to spell check a website?

Tags: html, spell-checking, browser-extension

Ideally, content should be spell-checked before being marked up with HTML. Unfortunately that does not always happen.

Once the content is integrated with HTML, it's very difficult to run that through a spell checker, e.g. by pasting into MS Word. What strategy should I use to spell check a website?

Comment: Cut and paste into MS Word isn’t particularly difficult. Implementing the corrections might be.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend browser extension, this is easy install and work or user output content, 
You can install Firefox [**Spell Checker**](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/spell-checker/) extension.

Answer (score 0):

I would say make a python script to take HTML in as a single text string and remove anything enclosed by <>. It wouldn't be perfect but you'd mostly have plaintext that can go into msword.

Answer (score 0):

Using a ide like netbeans is usually the best way to recheck HTML code or spell check your code. What do you ise to develope your websites